# Bootstrap 3 nav with submenu

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm having some issues trying to get my Bootstrap navigation to have a submenu.

I've created a jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/ho6ggmge/

NOTE: This was my first time using JSfiddle, so I wasn't sure how to include bootstrap files to the resources, so I just copied all of the CSS and JS into the sections there.

For the Javascript, everything that I've added is at the very bottom of the code, the rest is bootstrap.js, which I haven't touched.

For CSS, it's a little more scattered because I edited the bootstrap.css file quite a bit. If there's anything specific you need to find in the CSS and can't just let me know. The CSS for the submenu is all at the bottom of the code.

Now my issue is that when I click a link that is supposed to open a submenu (Job Info > Signoffs), the entire dropdown closes.

If you inspect element you can see that the .open class is added to the Signoffs link but it's removed from the Job Info link. I need them to both be open at the same time.

I took my code from this: http://www.bootply.com/97919 and was hoping to get mine working very similar to that.

Thank you very much for any and all help!

EDIT: I don't see this in your version, but when I take it out of mine the dropdown stops working completely:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown()
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your jsFiddle was way too cluttered to figure out what was going on... so here is what I did.

1. Created a new jsFiddle with Bootstrap 3.2 included from a CDN.
2. Included your `HTML` from your jsFiddle.
3. Included the custom `CSS` and `JavaScript` from the bootply example

The result is [This jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SchmalzyB/so7v14fm/) which seems to work correctly. So I am assuming your customizations are what is causing the issue.

EDIT:

After looking into it a little more, your issue was the below code. You were trageting `ul.dropdown` instead of `ul.dropdown-menu`. Adding the `-menu` seemed to resolve the issue in your jsFiddle.

Bootply example.

```
$('ul.dropdown-menu [data-toggle=dropdown]').on('click', function(event) {
```

Your code

```
$('ul.dropdown [data-toggle=dropdown]').on('click', function(event) {
```

Comment: Wow thanks. One last question, is it possible that something in the CSS could be causing this to not work? This is great though, I'll sort through everything I've done and try to figure it out. Just glad I know now that it could work! Thanks again :)

Comment: @noelllll See my edit above here is your original jsfiddle with the updated code  http://jsfiddle.net/SchmalzyB/fjf688uy/

Comment: Is that the only thing you changed? I see it's working on yours but when I change that on mine it doesn't do anything. It actually stops the open class from showing up on the Signoffs link. I'm going to edit my OP, there's a bit of code I'm not seeing in yours which I think might be why, but when I take it out of mine the whole nav doesn't work

Comment: @noelllll Sorry, I forgot there were a couple things that I forgot I removed. Removed jQuery Mobile and jQuery UI, as they were throwing from javascript errors. Also removed the `$(document).ready(function(){ $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown()});` because it is not necessary.

Comment: I don't know man this is starting to give me a headache lol. I've stripped my header down to the bare minimum, with only the nav HTML, bootstrap.css, bootstrap.js, and my global.css files included. I took out jQuery UI/Mobile and it's still not working. It works when I do it on my jsfiddle but not on the actual site. So frustrating

Comment: EDIT: NEVERMIND! It was ALL in the arrangement of including the files in the <head>. Thank you very much again for your time and help :)!

Answer (score 0):

Jus Add below code in your css. This works on hover....

```
ul.nav li.dropdown:hover > ul.dropdown-menu {
    display: block;    
}
```

Comment: I do like that, but it messes up the mobile version of the nav pretty bad. If there's a way to make it work on mobile as well that would be great

Comment: you can restrict that by adding @media property in css.. for screen size greater than 992px you can make it hover and for less then that you can make it onclick.. :)